# Linq Where Clause Column sequence Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

I want to know that if there are multiple columns in Linq whether the Column Order sequence matters in regards with performance.

Example :-

```
var listCalculation = ctx.Calculation.ToList();

var data = listCalculation.Where(m=>m.EmployeeId == item.employeeId && m.FieldName == item.FieldName).FirstOrDefault();
OR
var data = listCalculation.Where(m=> m.FieldName == item.FieldName && m.EmployeeId == item.employeeId).FirstOrDefault();
```

In the first linq EmployeeId is first & then FieldName & in second linq FieldName is first & then EmployeeId.

Suppose there are 1 million records in the listCalculation whether there will be a performance change in the above 2 queries?
How should we keep sequence of Columns in Where clause for best performance?

Comment: It's got nothing to do with LINQ, it's about how SQL Server decides to process it.

Comment: @DavidG the linq query is using the List populated from SQL. it is not actually hitting the SQL. But i will also like to know How should be the sequence in SQL query also.

Comment: Oh hang on, so this has nothing to do with SQL Server either then, because the first line takes all the data into memory.

Comment: It depends on uniqueness of each field as it relates to the value being checked. If EmployeeId is the same for the first 10K records and `FieldName` wont match until the last one then it would be more efficient to check on FieldName first. The inverse is also true. Also it is more efficient to do a string comparison check where you pass how you want the strings compared using StringComparer.Ordinal or StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase : `string.Equals(a,b,StringComparer.Ordinal)`

Comment: That said order of checks could be a micro optimization especially if you have the option to do this in Sql instead of in memory which would increase the performance tremendously because you no longer need to pull everything into memory first.

Comment: Finally consider creating a dictionary if it must be in memory and the collection is accessed many times (like in a loop) where you need to get an item by key. The key could be artificial like `EmployeeId + "|" + FieldName`.